# Convert CamelCase to snake_case

Tags: sql, postgresql

need result of following query

```
select regexp_replace('StackOverflow', 'something', 'something')
```

as

```
stack_overflow
```

Comment: Sorry to mention, but for each upper case character occurrence, it should replace it with "_" trailing with its lower case

Comment: so your desired output should be: _stack_overflow  Is it correct?

Comment: what did you try? which errors did you get. please invest more time to find an answer, we are not here to do your work, but to help you, if you are stuck

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following regex adds an underscore in front of every uppercase letter:

```
regexp_replace(name, '([A-Z])','_\1', 'g'))
```

As that results in on underscore at the beginning, this needs to be removed using `trim()`

```
trim(both '_' from lower(regexp_replace(name, '([A-Z])','_\1', 'g')))
```

The following query:

```
with names (name) as (
  values ('StackOverflow'), 
         ('Foo'), 
         ('FooBar'), 
         ('foobar'), 
         ('StackOverflowCom')
)
select name, trim(both '_' from lower(regexp_replace(name, '([A-Z])','_\1', 'g'))) as new_name
from names;
```

returns:

```
name             | new_name          
-----------------+-------------------
StackOverflow    | stack_overflow    
Foo              | foo               
FooBar           | foo_bar           
foobar           | foobar            
StackOverflowCom | stack_overflow_com
```

Comment: sorry champ, but failed with following string
StackOverflowCom
coming stack_overflowcom
expected stack_overflow_com

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want here

```
lower(
  regexp_replace(
    replace(column_name, ' ', '_'),
    '([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])',
    '\1_\2',
    'g'
  )
)
```

Here we test it,

```
WITH t (name) as (
  VALUES ('StackOverflow'), 
    ('Foo'), 
    ('FooBar'), 
    ('foobar'), 
    ('StackOverflowCom'),
    ('BLEHHHHokBaz')  -- doesn't go funky
)
SELECT name, lower(
  regexp_replace(
    replace(name, ' ', '_'),
    '([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])',
    '\1_\2',
    'g'
  )
) AS new_name
FROM t;
```

This has the advantage over @a_horse_with_no_name that it'll work with contiguous capital letters, and solves spaces too.

Also see,

- [How do I adopt the PostgreSQL naming convention in legacy database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/202445/2639)

Answer (score 2):

**SnakeCase to CamelCase**

```
SELECT REPLACE(INITCAP('hamza_rajput'), '_',' ') as camel_case;
```

**CamelCase to SnakeCase**

```
SELECT LOWER(regexp_replace('hamzaRajput', '([A-Z])','_\1', 'g')) as snake_case;
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it match existing libs output in other languages and to cover non-alphanumeric symbols it's better to do something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION to_snake_case(source text) RETURNS TEXT AS $$
DECLARE
result text;
BEGIN
  -- replace non-alphanumeric by '_'
  result = regexp_replace(source, '[^a-zA-Z_\d]', '_', 'g');
  -- prefix uppercase groups by '_' and make everything lowercase
  result = lower(regexp_replace(result, '([A-Z]+)' , '_\1', 'g'));
  -- reduce repeating '_'
  result = regexp_replace(result, '_+', '_', 'g');
  -- remove '_' from both ends
  result = btrim(result, '_');
  
  -- optionally
  IF result = '' THEN result = '_'; END IF;

  RETURN result;
END; $$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```