# Convert snake_case to camelCase - Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need the opposite of this basically.

[Convert CamelCase to snake_case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39695992/convert-camelcase-to-snake-case)

I have a string field which is a snake case identifier.
I want to convert it to camel case.

Is there a reliable and easy way to do this in Postgres?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get CamelCase.

1. Replace the _ with spaces.
2. Uppercase each word with initcap.
3. Remove the spaces.

And if you specifically want camelCase.

4. Lower case the first letter.

```
create function lcfirst(word text)
returns text
language plpgsql
immutable
as $$
begin
  return lower(left(word, 1)) || right(word, -1);
end;
$$;

create function camel_case(snake_case text)
returns text
language plpgsql
immutable
as $$
begin
  return
    replace(
      initcap(
        replace(snake_case, '_', ' ')
      ),
      ' ', ''
    );
end;
$$;

select lcfirst(camel_case('snek_snek_snek'));
   lcfirst    
--------------
 snekSnekSnek
```

See [Other String Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER).

Comment: This is not camel case. The first letter is capitalized too which is not quite what we want.

Comment: @peter.petrov Please make that clear in your question, you reference CamelCase. I will adjust the answer.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear initially. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use INITCAP()

```
SELECT name, INITCAP(name) FROM customer
```

result

```
JOHN         John
marie lisa   Marie Lisa
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tocamel(str text)
    returns text
        LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $function$
        begin
                return lower(left(str, 1)) 
                    || right(replace(
                            initcap(replace(str, '_', ' '))
                        , ' ', ''), -1);
        END;
    $function$
    ;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION snake_to_camel(text)
RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE
    input_text text := $1;
    output_text text := '';
    last_char_was_underscore boolean := false;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..length(input_text) LOOP
        IF substring(input_text, i, 1) = '_' THEN
            last_char_was_underscore := true;
        ELSE
            IF last_char_was_underscore THEN
                output_text := output_text || upper(substring(input_text, i, 1));
                last_char_was_underscore := false;
            ELSE
                output_text := output_text || lower(substring(input_text, i, 1));
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN output_text;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

To use this function, call it with the snake case string as an argument, like this:

```
SELECT snake_to_camel('some_snake_case_string');
```