# Convert camelCase to snake_case not returning expected output MySQL 8

Tags: mysql, regex, mysql-8.0

I am trying to write a text transformation in a `SELECT` statement to convert variable names from **camelCase to upper SNAKE_CASE**. I'm on MySQL v.8.0.26.

For example: `thisIsTheVar` should become `THIS_IS_THE_VAR`

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39695992/convert-camelcase-to-snake-case), but the solution has parameters that my version of MySQL says are invalid (the 'g') (Edit: This solution was for Postgres, but I wanted to document what I had tried).

After some reading, I wrote this:

```
SELECT UPPER(CONCAT(SUBSTRING('thisIsTheVar', 1, 1),
     REGEXP_REPLACE(SUBSTRING('thisIsTheVar', 2), '([A-Z])', '_\\1')));
```

But this returns:

`T_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1`

Anything obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: *but the solution has parameters that my version of MySQL says are invalid* Why you're surprized that the solution for PostgreSQL does not work on MySQL?

Comment: Hi @Akina this comment is unhelpful, I'm presenting my full thought process.

Comment: PostgreSQL and MySQL are different programs, not different versions. You can't generally use the same syntax or features.

Comment: In MySQL use `$1` instead of `\1` as a backreference, and it needs parentheses around the pattern to be referenced. 
`upper(regexp_replace('thisIsTheVar' collate utf8mb4_bin, '([A-Z])', '_$1'))`

Comment: Your reference to an earlier answer is not very valid.  MySQL has been updated to include regular expression replace and the up to date answer will be MUCH simpler than that answer.

Comment: @BillKarwin Thank you, a mod closed my question, but your answer worked for me. The $ sign instead of \ plus the collation was the trick.

Comment: I was able to reopen the question and post my solution as an answer. The question was closed by a non-moderator user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, use `$1` instead of `\1` as a backreference, and it needs parentheses around the pattern to be referenced.

```
upper(regexp_replace('thisIsTheVar' collate utf8mb4_bin, '([A-Z])', '_$1'))
```