# convert camelCase to snake_case psql encoding issue

Tags: sql, postgresql, encoding, psql

I have been solving the task converting camelCase -> snake_case on SQL level, however I met strange issue with encoding.

so I have the table with type column

```sql
select distinct type from my_table;
                    type                     
---------------------------------------------
 Foo::FooBar
 Foo::BazQux
```

and I want to convert and update it in the following column

```sql
select distinct code from my_table;
                    code                     
---------------------------------------------
 foo_bar
 baz_qux
```

I found the code in other similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39695992/convert-camelcase-to-snake-case)
slightly modified it

```sql
UPDATE my_table
SET code = LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(type, '::', 2), '([a-z])([A-Z])', '\1_\2', 'g'));
```

however it produces the following:

```sql
select distinct code from my_table;
                    code                     
---------------------------------------------
fo\x01_\x02ar
ba\x01_\x02ux
```

I can't get why replacing matching groups produces encoding issue?

```
psql (PostgreSQL) 15.4

SHOW SERVER_ENCODING;
 server_encoding 
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 row)
```

Comment: For whatever reason, the placeholders were treated as escape sequences. `\1` and `\x01` are two different escape sequences for the `0x01` character. This isn't an encoding issue.

Comment: ok, thanks for pointing me that it is not encoding issue, what else it can be? Maybe you have some ideas where to dig? I solved the task the other way hardcoding type values (there're not many of them, yet.) but I want to find dynamic solution. Currently have no clue where to look

Comment: What's the *actual* query? According to [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE),  PostgreSQL should only use C-style escape sequences like `\1` if the `E` prefix is used, eg `E'\1_\2'`, or if non-standard configuration parameters were used. If that's the case, double the backslash character, ie `'\\1_\\2'`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `\\1_\\2` works thank you! Could you post this as answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: That's not a full answer - why are C-style escape sequences enabled by default? Was `standard_conforming_strings` turned off? Was this intentional or an accident?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't happen *unless* C-style escape sequences are enabled, by turning `standard_conforming_strings` off. The bytes show that `\1` and `\2` were treated as C-style escape sequences, in which case they represent the bytes `0x01` and `0x02`. Another way to represent them is `\x01` and `\x02`, which is what the output shows.

The [documentation explains](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE) that normally, PostgreSQL would only use C-style escape sequences if the string had the `E` prefix :

```
E'\1_\2'
```

> PostgreSQL also accepts “escape” string constants, which are an extension to the SQL standard. An escape string constant is specified by writing the letter E (upper or lower case) just before the opening single quote, e.g., E'foo'
>
> If the configuration parameter standard_conforming_strings is off, then PostgreSQL recognizes backslash escapes in both regular and escape string constants. However, as of PostgreSQL 9.1, the default is on, meaning that backslash escapes are recognized only in escape string constants.

The quick fix in this case is to escape the backslash character itself :

```
\\1_\\2
```

The real solution would be to investigate why `standard_conforming_strings` is off and whether that was intentional. If not, the DBA may change it in the future, breaking any patterns that escape the backslash

Comment: standard_conforming_strings 
-----------------------------
 on
(1 row)

it is enabled in my db, maybe something else to check too?